# Изменение состояние при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

В проекте имеется несколько section'ов. Один из них выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в следующем. Во время прокрутки данного section'а он должен менять свое состояние(то есть иметь `position:fixed`, но его `min-height: 1470px`). А также все пункты должны доходить до воронки и плавно исчезать (не зависимо от их количества). Причем этот блок должен быть полностью адаптивным.

Comment: можно было картинку добавить в прошлый вопрос, зачем одигаковые плодить

Comment: @StrangerintheQ боялся, что до того вопроса не дойдут:)

Comment: я бы Вам давно помог, если бы понял что Вы хотите, теперь кажется понял, но сделаю уже попозже, если никто Вам не ответи

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо вам большое!

Comment: не за что пока что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повозившись еще немного, решил проблему самостоятельно:) Решение представлено чуть ниже:

```js
const scroll = document.querySelector('.list-tools'),
  content = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-content div');
let itemsCount = content.length - 1;

content.forEach((value, index) => {
  value.style.position = 'absolute';
  value.style.top = 0;
  value.style.width = '100%';
  value.style.height = '100px';
  value.style.opacity = 0;
  value.style.transition = 'all .4s ease-in';
  if (index == content.length - 1) {
    value.style.opacity = 1;
  }
});

scroll.addEventListener('mousewheel', onWheel);


function onWheel(e) {
  let delta = e.deltaY;
  if (delta > 0) {
    //при скролле вниз
    itemsCount--;
    let copyThisLength = -1;
    if (itemsCount >= 0) {
      copyThisLength = itemsCount;
      content[copyThisLength].style.opacity = 1;
    }
    while (copyThisLength < content.length - 1) {
      content[copyThisLength + 1].style.top = `${parseInt(content[copyThisLength+1].style.top) + delta / 1.5}px`;
      copyThisLength++;
    }
  } else {
    //при скролле вверх
    console.log(delta);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
div.list-tools {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 875px;
  /*при задании следующей высоты этот блок идеально доходил до воронки. т.е. это крайняя точка*/
}

div.list-tools_ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 875px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="list-tools">
    <div class="list-tools_ul">
      <div class="scroll-content">
        <div class="list-tools__item white">Заголовок №1</div>
        <div class="list-tools__item white">Заголовок №2</div>
        <div class="list-tools__item white">Заголовок №3</div>
        <div class="list-tools__item white">Заголовок №4</div>
        <div class="list-tools__item white">Заголовок №5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```